# Selecting currencies on a form using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have written the following code for the selenium Python select function and the code works fine.

```
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("currencyid")).select_by_visible_text("AUD")
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("excur")).select_by_visible_text("AUD")

select1 = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("currencyid")).first_selected_option.text
select2 = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("excur")).first_selected_option.text
assert select1 == "USD"
assert select2 == "CAD"
```

Is there anything I can do this to reduce the steps and to make it cleaner? Do I need to define the ids twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to recreate the `Select` instances, *define once and reuse*:

```
currency = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("currencyid"))
excur = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("excur"))

currency.select_by_visible_text("AUD")
excur.select_by_visible_text("AUD")

assert currency.first_selected_option.text == "USD"  # should not be "AUD"?
assert excur.first_selected_option.text == "CAD"  # should not be "AUD"?
```

If you have more select elements, this approach would not scale well, you can further improve the code and put the logic into a loop, something like:

```
values = [("currencyid", "AUD"), ("excur", "AUD")]
for id, value in values:
    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id(id))
    select.select_by_visible_text(value)

    assert select.first_selected_option.text == value
```